# Plot Seaborn Barplots in Subplots with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, bar-chart, seaborn

I have two files as input, that look as follows:

```
col1 col2
A B
C C
B A
A A
A C
C A
B B
```

Meaning, I have two columns with letters, separated by spaces. I want to plot the number of the occurrences of those letters, each column in its own barplot. Assume that both files have a different distribution of letters.

This is the code:

```
from collections import Counter
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

inputDir = "/tmp/files/"

inputFiles = [ f for f in listdir(inputDir) if isfile(join(inputDir, f)) ]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), ncols=2, nrows=len(inputFiles))

z=0

while inputFiles:

  files = inputFiles[0]
  inputFiles.remove(files)

  c = Counter()
  a = Counter()

  x1 = []
  y1 = []
  x2 = []
  y2 = []

  with open(inputDir + files, "r") as f2:
    for line in f2:
      line = line.strip()
      if line.split(" ")[0] != "col1":
        c[str(line.split(" ")[0])] += 1
        a[str(line.split(" ")[1])] += 1

  try:
    for cc in c:
      x1.append(cc)
      y1.append(c[cc])
    row = z // 2
    col = z % 2
    ax_curr = axes[row, col]
    sns.barplot(x1, y1, ax=ax_curr)

    z+=1

    for aa in a:
      x2.append(aa)
      y2.append(a[aa])
    row = z // 2
    col = z % 2
    ax_curr = axes[row, col]
    sns.barplot(x2, y2, ax=ax_curr)

    z+=1

  except:
    continue

sns.plt.show()
```

The result should be one image, where I have the following barplots as subplots:

```
---------------------------------------
|                  |                  |
|                  |                  |
|   barplot col1   |   barplot col2   |
|        file1     |       file1      |
|                  |                  |
--------------------------------------|
|                  |                  |
|                  |                  |
|   barplot col1   |   barplot col2   |
|        file2     |       file2      |
|                  |                  |
---------------------------------------
```

So the height of each bar should correspond to the number of each letter.

The problem until now is, that the bars in each subplot look completely different and I cant find out why. Please let me know, if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is unclear what "completely" different means here, it could be that you need to strip the lines before splitting them. Otherwise the values of the last column could look like `"B "` instead of `"B"`. Also I'm not sure why you try to convert a string to an integer in `c[int(line.split(" ")[0])] += 1`. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Try:

```
with open(inputDir + files, "r") as f2:
      for line in f2:
          line = line.strip()
          if line.split(" ")[0] != "col1":
              c[line.split(" ")[0]] += 1
              a[line.split(" ")[1]] += 1
```

Comment: You are completely right- I had different data and adjusted my code in the night to the new datafiles without running them. Sorry for that. I adjusted my code and it still doesn't work. In the left upper corner I have thousands of bars, in the upper right corner there are only a few bars (which cannot be correct, since there are about 100k lines in both files).

Comment: I hope you understand that we need to talk about the problem on the basis of the information we both have available here. So if you have a problem with data that is different from what you show in the question, it's hard to help you out. You would then need to create a new [MCVE], reducing the data to an amount which can be shared here, but still reproduces the issue.